# Active Admin logout redirect loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, cancan

I've installed Active Admin, Devise and CanCan, plus configured the CanCan adapter (as per the instructions on Active Admin's wiki). The problem I have is that when the user logs out, the system doesn't redirect correctly to the login page. It seems to enter an infinite redirect loop i.e. Safari says 'too many redirects' and 'Failed to open page'. This happens indefinitely until I stop/start the server and clear out the cache/cookies to kill any live cookie sessions.

My system has two levels of admin: 'basic_admin' and 'super_admin'. All valid users should have access to the Active Admin back-end (there is no front-end - it's a data-driven dashboard system).

```
routes.rb:

  devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

active_admin.rb:

  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_user!
  config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
  config.on_unauthorized_access = :access_denied
  config.current_user_method = :current_user
  config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
  config.on_unauthorized_access = :access_denied
  config.cancan_ability_class = 'Ability'
  config.logout_link_path = :destroy_user_session_path
  config.filter_attributes = [:encrypted_password, :password, :password_confirmation]
  config.localize_format = :long

ability.rb:

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    # Standard permissions for all users (basic and super admins)
    can :read, ActiveAdmin::Page, :name => 'Dashboard'
    can :manage, ServiceUser
    can :manage, SupportSession, support_worker_id: user.support_worker_id
    can :create, SupportSession
    can :manage, User, id: user.id  # Can manage only their own account

    if user.role == 'super_admin'  # Extra permissions for super admins
      can :manage, :all
    end
  end
end

Console log (rails server terminal):

Started GET "/admin/login" for ::1 at 2019-06-14 08:43:23 +0100
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I've fixed this. I suspect the solution has something to do with my application controller. I commented out these two lines inserted by Devise (which I installed before ActiveAdmin)

application_controller.rb:

```
#protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true
#before_action :authenticate_user!
```